# how to make a create route to create an array list in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to save a document with a list of array, but it just doesn't work as I want. I'm using nodejs with mongoose.

Here is my code:

```js
clinMedExamRouter.post("/clin_exam_med", (req, res, next) => {
  async function newData() {
    const data = new ClinicasMedicosExames({
      clinicaId: req.body.clinicaId,
      medico: [
        {
          medicoId: req.body.medicoId
        }
      ]
    });

    try {
      const result = await data.save();
      console.log("Operação realizada com sucesso");
      console.log(req.body);
      res.status(201).send({ message: "Cadastrado com sucesso!" });
    } catch (erro) {
      console.log(erro.message);
      res.status(406).send({ message: "Cadastro falhou" });
    }
  }

  newData();
});
```

And this is my model:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ClinicaMedicoExameSchema = new Schema(
  {
    clinicaId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "clinicas"
    },
    medico: [
      {
        medicoId: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "medicos"
        }
      }
    ],
    exame_consulta: [
      {
        exameConsultaId: {
          type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref: "exames_consultas"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("clin_exam_med", ClinicaMedicoExameSchema);
```

Can someone please help me to figure this out?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use `Model.create` method. You just need to use a request body which is similar to your schema.

Also there is no need to define a function in your route.

```js
clinMedExamRouter.post("/clin_exam_med", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  try {
    const result = await ClinicasMedicosExames.create(req.body);
    console.log("Operação realizada com sucesso");
    res.status(201).send({ message: "Cadastrado com sucesso!" });
  } catch (erro) {
    console.log(erro.message);
    res.status(406).send({ message: "Cadastro falhou" });
  }
});
```

Comment: @LocalizaMed you are welcome, I appreciate if you can also upvote the answer.